# How to use Tensorflow and Sci-Kit Learn together in one environment in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, tensorflow, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 . I tried to install Tensorflow using Anaconda 2 . But it installed a Environment inside ubuntu . So i had to create a virtual environment and then use Tensorflow . Now how can i use both Tensorflow and Sci-kit learn together in a single environment .

Comment: Did you try this: conda install scikit-learn?
Full instructions are here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda `defaults` doesn't provide tensorflow yet, but `conda-forge` do, conda `install -c conda-forge tensorflow` should see you right, though (for others reading!) the installed tensorflow will not work on CentOS < 7 (or other Linux Distros of a similar vintage).

Answer (score 0):

there are many options to install, but for example if you use #pip method, you can install #tensorflow using: 
    sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-virtualenv

then complete the process following the official instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation

example python2.7:

```
(tensorflow)$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

(tensorflow)$ pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

and into the same virtual-environment install scikit-learn using same pip-method: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

in terminal, activate tensorflow by

```
source activate tensorflow
```

then, install scikitlearn using:

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

Then, you'll have scikit-learn and tensorflow in the same environment.